Meta Llama-3 prompt sample
I am trying to ask Llama-3 model to read a document and then answer my questions, but my code seems does not generate any output. Can someone tell me what’s wrong with the code? I appreciate it.
Code:
from huggingface_hub import login
login(token=‘my_token’)
import transformers
import torch

model_id = “Meta-Llama-3-8B”
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
“text-generation”,
model=model_id,
model_kwargs={“torch_dtype”: torch.bfloat16},
device=“cuda”,
)

notes_path = ‘note1.txt’
with open(notes_path, ‘r’, encoding=‘utf-8’) as file:
    cal_notes = file.read()

prompt = f"“”<begin_of_text><start_header_id>system<end_header_id>
{cal_notes}<leot_id><start_header_id>user<end_header_id>
My question.<leot_id><start_header_id>assistant<end_header_id>“”"

outputs = pipeline(prompt, max_new_tokens=512)
generated_text = outputs[0][‘generated_text’]

print(generated_text)

I ran the code and the output only contains the text in note1.txt and myquestions, I did not see any generated answer from Llama-3.

This isn't your immediate problem, but note that "“” is not """, and ‘ is not '. Be sure you use a programmers' editor that turns off "smart quotes" and other OS-type helpers -- if code as you put it here were put to a Python interpreter it would cause a SyntaxError because of the invalid characters.

Anyhow, one obvious problem here (though it may or may not be the only problem) is that Meta-Llama-3-8B is not instruct-trained, so it doesn't know how to act as an assistant. You should be using Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct if you want it to try to actually answer your questions as opposed to predict text that comes after them.

If you are going to use the Instruct variant, I would recommend to use the apply_chat_template function. HF Docs
